# Slice a dataframe based on the first particular value shows up

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a slice a dataframe in pandas like this:

```
index  a    b
0      A    -
1      A    +
2      A    -
3      B    -
4      C    +
5      C    -
```

I want to keep all the rows after the first '+', grouped by column A, and delete all the rows in each group starting with '-'.
The outcome should be like this:

```
index  a    b
1      A    +
2      A    -
4      C    +
5      C    -
```

How to do this?

Comment: can you give more details on "*delete all the rows in each group starting with '-'*"?

Comment: What would be the output on `pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'b': ['-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '-']})`

Comment: @mozway Should be pd.DataFrame({'a': [ 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'b': [ '+', '-', '+', '+', '-', '-']}) . If the group is start with +, then keep all rows. If the group is start with -, then delete these rows with -, until the first + shows up and then keep all the rest rows.

Comment: I don't know if I correctly @mozway...Why there is no "reply" button?

Comment: yes you replied to me (an all) @Canvas. Then my first answer works (or the first one of jezrael that is the same with a more complicated syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with compare `b` for `+` for keep all rows after first `+` per groups:

```
df1 = (df[df.assign(new = lambda x: x['b'].eq('+'))
       .groupby('a')['new']
       .cummax()])

print (df1)
   a  b
1  A  +
2  A  -
4  C  +
5  C  -
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Tried and it works well. Sorry, I can't vote up. How to get reputation points?

Answer (score 1):

Simple syntax, use `groupby` on Series with `cummax`:

```
df[df['b'].eq('+').groupby(df['a']).cummax()]
```

output:

```
   index  a  b
1      1  A  +
2      2  A  -
4      4  C  +
5      5  C  -
```

If you also want to delete groups that start with `-` ("*delete all the rows in each group starting with '-'*"), you can combine `cummin`/`cummax`:

```
df[df['b'].ne('-').groupby(df['a']).apply(lambda s: s.cummin().cummax())]
```

output:

```
   index  a  b
4      4  C  +
5      5  C  -
```

Comment: it is first part of my answer, missing second part for test `-`

Comment: @jezrael what do you mean missing `-`?

Comment: `and delete all the rows in each group starting with '-'`

Comment: @jezrael group A starts with `-` and is not deleted

Comment: @jezrael not sure this is what is expected but I updated for such alternative ;)

Comment: yes, agree, good idea is created comment